# Use @Test annotation and ActivityTestRule with Robotium (Espresso-way)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, junit, robotium

I wonder how can i mark my test as @Test like in JUnit, because so far I have to use 'test...' name. It means:

```
@Test
private void creatingAcc(){
```

instead of

```
private void testCreatingAcc(){
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Follow these steps to achieve it:

1. Go to your's app `build.gradle` file and add test dependendencies like below:

   ```
       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.1'
       compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.6.1'
   ```

   Now your `build.gradle` should look like:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
           compileSdkVersion 24
           buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

   defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.example.piotr.myapplication"
         minSdkVersion 15
         targetSdkVersion 21
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
         testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }

      buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }

      }
   }

   dependencies {
          compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
          testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
          compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
          compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
          androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
          androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
          androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.1'
          compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.6.1'    
   }
   ```
2. Then you need to go to your `androidTest` directory and create Java class and name it for example `MyActivityTestRule`
3. In this file put code below:

   ```
   @Beta
   public class MyActivityTestRule<T extends Activity> extends UiThreadTestRule {

   private static final String TAG = "ActivityInstrumentationRule";

   private final Class<T> mActivityClass;

   public Instrumentation getInstrumentation() {
       return mInstrumentation;
   }

   private Instrumentation mInstrumentation;

   private boolean mInitialTouchMode = false;

   private boolean mLaunchActivity = false;

   private T mActivity;

   /**
    * Similar to {@link #MyActivityTestRule(Class, boolean, boolean)} but with "touch mode" disabled.
    *
    * @param activityClass    The activity under test. This must be a class in the instrumentation
    *                         targetPackage specified in the AndroidManifest.xml
    * @see MyActivityTestRule#MyActivityTestRule(Class, boolean, boolean)
    */
   public MyActivityTestRule(Class<T> activityClass) {
       this(activityClass, false);
   }

   /**
    * Similar to {@link #MyActivityTestRule(Class, boolean, boolean)} but defaults to launch the
    * activity under test once per
    * <a href="http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Test.html"><code>Test</code></a> method.
    * It is launched before the first
    * <a href="http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html"><code>Before</code></a>
    * method, and terminated after the last
    * <a href="http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html"><code>After</code></a>
    * method.
    *
    * @param activityClass    The activity under test. This must be a class in the instrumentation
    *                         targetPackage specified in the AndroidManifest.xml
    * @param initialTouchMode true if the Activity should be placed into "touch mode" when started
    * @see MyActivityTestRule#MyActivityTestRule(Class, boolean, boolean)
    */
   public MyActivityTestRule(Class<T> activityClass, boolean initialTouchMode) {
       this(activityClass, initialTouchMode, true);
   }

   /**
    * Creates an {@link MyActivityTestRule} for the Activity under test.
    *
    * @param activityClass    The activity under test. This must be a class in the instrumentation
    *                         targetPackage specified in the AndroidManifest.xml
    * @param initialTouchMode true if the Activity should be placed into "touch mode" when started
    * @param launchActivity   true if the Activity should be launched once per
    *                         <a href="http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Test.html">
    *                         <code>Test</code></a> method. It will be launched before the first
    *                         <a href="http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html">
    *                         <code>Before</code></a> method, and terminated after the last
    *                         <a href="http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html">
    *                         <code>After</code></a> method.
    */
   public MyActivityTestRule(Class<T> activityClass, boolean initialTouchMode,
                             boolean launchActivity) {
       mActivityClass = activityClass;
       mInitialTouchMode = initialTouchMode;
       mLaunchActivity = launchActivity;
       mInstrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
   }

   /**
    * Override this method to set up Intent as if supplied to
    * {@link android.content.Context#startActivity}.
    * <p>
    * The default Intent (if this method returns null or is not overwritten) is:
    * action = {@link Intent#ACTION_MAIN}
    * flags = {@link Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK}
    * All other intent fields are null or empty.
    *
    * @return The Intent as if supplied to {@link android.content.Context#startActivity}.
    */
   protected Intent getActivityIntent() {
       return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   }

   /**
    * Override this method to execute any code that should run before your {@link Activity} is
    * created and launched.
    * This method is called before each test method, including any method annotated with
    * <a href="http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html"><code>Before</code></a>.
    */
   protected void beforeActivityLaunched() {
       // empty by default
   }

   /**
    * Override this method to execute any code that should run after your {@link Activity} is
    * launched, but before any test code is run including any method annotated with
    * <a href="http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html"><code>Before</code></a>.
    * <p>
    * Prefer
    * <a href="http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html"><code>Before</code></a>
    * over this method. This method should usually not be overwritten directly in tests and only be
    * used by subclasses of MyActivityTestRule to get notified when the activity is created and
    * visible but test runs.
    */
   protected void afterActivityLaunched() {
       // empty by default
   }

   /**
    * Override this method to execute any code that should run after your {@link Activity} is
    * finished.
    * This method is called after each test method, including any method annotated with
    * <a href="http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html"><code>After</code></a>.
    */
   protected void afterActivityFinished() {
       // empty by default
   }

   /**
    * @return The activity under test.
    */
   public T getActivity() {
       if (mActivity == null) {
           Log.w(TAG, "Activity wasn't created yet");
       }
       return mActivity;
   }

   @Override
   public Statement apply(final Statement base, Description description) {
       return new ActivityStatement(super.apply(base, description));
   }

   /**
    * Launches the Activity under test.
    * <p>
    * Don't call this method directly, unless you explicitly requested not to launch the Activity
    * manually using the launchActivity flag in
    * {@link MyActivityTestRule#MyActivityTestRule(Class, boolean, boolean)}.
    * <p>
    * Usage:
    * <pre>
    *    &#064;Test
    *    public void customIntentToStartActivity() {
    *        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    *        mActivity = mActivityRule.launchActivity(intent);
    *    }
    * </pre>
    * @param startIntent The Intent that will be used to start the Activity under test. If
    *                    {@code startIntent} is null, the Intent returned by
    *                    {@link MyActivityTestRule#getActivityIntent()} is used.
    * @return the Activity launched by this rule.
    * @see MyActivityTestRule#getActivityIntent()
    */
   public T launchActivity(@Nullable Intent startIntent) {
       // set initial touch mode
       mInstrumentation.setInTouchMode(mInitialTouchMode);

       final String targetPackage = mInstrumentation.getTargetContext().getPackageName();
       // inject custom intent, if provided
       if (null == startIntent) {
           startIntent = getActivityIntent();
           if (null == startIntent) {
               Log.w(TAG, "getActivityIntent() returned null using default: " +
                       "Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)");
               startIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
           }
       }
       startIntent.setClassName(targetPackage, mActivityClass.getName());
       startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       Log.d(TAG, String.format("Launching activity %s",
               mActivityClass.getName()));

       beforeActivityLaunched();
       // The following cast is correct because the activity we're creating is of the same type as
       // the one passed in
       mActivity = mActivityClass.cast(mInstrumentation.startActivitySync(startIntent));

       mInstrumentation.waitForIdleSync();

       afterActivityLaunched();
       return mActivity;
   }

   // Visible for testing
   void setInstrumentation(Instrumentation instrumentation) {
       mInstrumentation = checkNotNull(instrumentation, "instrumentation cannot be null!");
   }

   void finishActivity() {
       if (mActivity != null) {
           mActivity.finish();
           mActivity = null;
       }
   }

   /**
    * <a href="http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/runners/model/Statement.html">
    * <code>Statement</code></a> that finishes the activity after the test was executed
    */
   private class ActivityStatement extends Statement {

       private final Statement mBase;

       public ActivityStatement(Statement base) {
           mBase = base;
       }

       @Override
       public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
           try {
               if (mLaunchActivity) {
                   mActivity = launchActivity(getActivityIntent());
               }
               mBase.evaluate();
           } finally {
               finishActivity();
               afterActivityFinished();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Well, to be honest, it's standard `ActivityTestRule` with additional getter `getInstrumentation()`, which I would used in my test class.

4. Create a new Java class - it would be your test class and put the code below:

   ```
   @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) 
   public class MainActivityTest {

   private Solo solo;

   private static final String MAIN_ACTIVITY = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

   @Rule
   public MyActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new MyActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

   @Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
       solo = new Solo(mActivityRule.getInstrumentation(), mActivityRule.getActivity());
   }

   @Test
   public void checkIfMainActivityIsProperlyDisplayed() throws InterruptedException {
       solo.waitForActivity("MainActivity", 2000);
       solo.assertCurrentActivity(mActivityRule.getActivity().getString(
               R.string.error_no_class_def_found, MAIN_ACTIVITY), MAIN_ACTIVITY);
       solo.getText("Hello World").isShown();

     }
   }
   ```

As you see it's not difficult as might be.

Hope it will help

Comment: This also might be useful: http://wiebe-elsinga.com/blog/whats-new-in-android-testing/

Comment: It'd help if I only have MainActivity there, but there is a problem, cos I test app on AVD. My Setup class extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, then I have priv static final field with LauncherActivity name of my app. the I have private static field launcherActivityClass of Class<?> type. Constructor got only super(launcherActivityClass). I set launcherActivityClass to Class.forName(appname). Then override setup with super.setUp(); solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation()); getActivity();. I'm not that good in Andoid studio, but Test, Before and so on annotations'd be great.

Comment: Change name of class from MainActivity to LauncherActivity

Comment: Could you edit your post and add the code from comment

Comment: I created new project then did all steps, but when I'm trying to run test it says _No tests found ..._.